# jQuery: Invoke an action when click inside a container, however, if I click on a component inside that container then dont invoke the action

Tags: jquery

What I have is: wherever I click inside `div` container, I will create a textbox at that position. What I did was basically catch the click event on the `div` container. Something like this

**EDIT**

```
<div id="noteCol">
    <textarea class="textBox"/>
    ...
</div>

<script>
     jQuery(".textBox").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
     });
     jQuery("#noteCol").click(function(e){
         ...
     });
</script>
```

The problem I have now is that, if I want to write on the textbox I just create, well I cant. Because since the textbox is created inside `div noteCol`, so when I try to click on that textbox to write something, jQuery catch the click event and create an textbox on top of my current textbox. How do I fix this situation? (Maybe something like have the same `class="textbox"` for all the textbox, and when I click inside `noteCol`, somehow detect if I click on `.textbox`) Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem. Since I dynamically create the `textarea`, the click event does not bind to the newly created `textarea`. I have to use `live`. Here is my solution

```
jQuery (".textBox").live("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
jQuery("#noteCol").live("click", function(e){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `event.preventDefault();` on click of text box.
something like this...

```
$('.textBox').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           //rest of your logic go here

});
```

refrence...[**preventDefault**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

**Updated**

i think in your case `stopPropagation()` is going to help you...

```
 $('.noteCol .textBox').click(function(e){
               e.stopPropagation();
               //rest of your logic will go here

    });
```

i think you are looking for above option.

i hope it helps you

Comment: I try but it does not seems to work. I just change my code, can u take a look at it, to see what I have is what u meant?

Comment: see updated answer...try to use  e.stopPropagation();, because e.preventDefault() is to prevent current event not to parent event.

Comment: Unfortunately that was my first thought as well, it does not work either. Any another idea?

Comment: give proper refrence to that textbox as i have did in my answer $('.noteCol .textBox').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();..........});

Comment: Actually the reason is because I dynamically create the `.textBox`, so the click event does not bind to the `.textBox`. I have to use `live("click", function(e){e.stopPropagation();});`